# How to filter only particular lines from a file?

Tags: awk, grep, cut, json

I have a file which has following lines. I just was to see IP address which is the first line, second line country only once and the score line only once but the score line should be the highest value which is 7.1 in this case.

```json
{
  "ip": "86.75.227.72",
  "history": [
    {
     "created": "2012-03-22T07:26:00.000Z",
     "reason": "Regional Internet Registry",
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.64.0.0/12",
     "categoryDescriptions": {},
     "reasonDescription": "One of the five RIRs announced a (new) location mapping of the IP.",
     "score": 1,
     "cats": {}
   },
   {
     "created": "2012-04-13T13:34:00.000Z",
     "reason": "DNS heuristics",
     "cats": {
       "Dynamic IPs": 100
     },
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.64.0.0/12",
     "categoryDescriptions": {
       "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines."
     },
     "reasonDescription": "Based on statistical DNS analysis.",
     "score": 1
   },
   {
     "created": "2014-01-22T19:08:00.000Z",
     "reason": "DNS heuristics",
     "cats": {
       "Dynamic IPs": 86
     },
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.72.0.0/14",
     "categoryDescriptions": {
       "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines."
     },
     "reasonDescription": "Based on statistical DNS analysis.",
     "score": 1
   },
   {
     "created": "2014-03-09T13:11:00.000Z",
     "reason": "DNS heuristics",
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.75.224.0/21",
     "cats": {
       "Dynamic IPs": 71
     },
     "categoryDescriptions": {
       "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines."
     },
     "reasonDescription": "Based on statistical DNS analysis.",
     "score": 1
   },
   {
     "created": "2017-07-26T06:24:00.000Z",
     "reason": "Regional Internet Registry",
     "asns": {
       "15557": {
         "Company": "LDCOMNET, FR",
         "cidr": 12
       }
     },
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.75.224.0/21",
     "cats": {
       "Dynamic IPs": 71
     },
     "categoryDescriptions": {
       "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines."
     },
     "reasonDescription": "One of the five RIRs announced a (new) location mapping of the IP.",
     "score": 1
   },
   {
     "created": "2017-10-10T06:23:00.000Z",
     "reason": "Regional Internet Registry",
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.75.224.0/21",
     "cats": {
       "Dynamic IPs": 71
     },
     "categoryDescriptions": {
       "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines."
     },
     "reasonDescription": "One of the five RIRs announced a (new) location mapping of the IP.",
     "score": 1
   },
   {
     "created": "2017-10-18T06:23:00.000Z",
     "reason": "Regional Internet Registry",
     "asns": {
       "15557": {
         "Company": "LDCOMNET, FR",
         "cidr": 12
       }
     },
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.75.224.0/21",
     "cats": {
       "Dynamic IPs": 71
     },
     "categoryDescriptions": {
       "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines."
     },
     "reasonDescription": "One of the five RIRs announced a (new) location mapping of the IP.",
     "score": 1
   },
   {
     "created": "2017-11-20T18:16:00.000Z",
     "reason": "Third party feed",
     "asns": {
       "15557": {
         "Company": "LDCOMNET, FR",
         "cidr": 12
       }
     },
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.75.227.72/32",
     "cats": {
       "Dynamic IPs": 71,
       "Bots": 71
     },
     "categoryDescriptions": {
       "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines.",
       "Bots": "IPs known for botnet-member activity. Devices using these IPs are obviously infected and take part in DDoS-attacks, port-scanning, spam-sending etc."
     },
     "reasonDescription": "This data was imported from a third party feed.",
     "score": 7.1
   },
   {
     "created": "2017-11-25T21:46:00.000Z",
     "reason": "Third party feed",
     "asns": {
       "15557": {
         "Company": "LDCOMNET, FR",
         "cidr": 12
       }
     },
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.75.227.72/32",
     "cats": {
       "Dynamic IPs": 71
     },
     "categoryDescriptions": {
       "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines."
     },
     "reasonDescription": "This data was imported from a third party feed.",
     "score": 1
   }
 ],
 "subnets": [
   {
     "created": "2017-10-18T06:23:00.000Z",
     "reason": "Regional Internet Registry",
     "asns": {
       "15557": {
         "Company": "LDCOMNET, FR",
         "cidr": 12
       }
     },
     "geo": {
       "country": "France",
       "countrycode": "FR"
     },
     "ip": "86.64.0.0",
     "categoryDescriptions": {},
     "reasonDescription": "One of the five RIRs announced a (new) location mapping of the IP.",
     "score": 1,
     "cats": {},
     "subnet": "86.64.0.0/12"
   },
   {
     "created": "2014-03-09T13:11:00.000Z",
     "reason": "DNS heuristics",
     "cats": {
       "Dynamic IPs": 71
     },
     "ip": "86.75.224.0",
     "categoryDescriptions": {
       "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines."
     },
     "reasonDescription": "Based on statistical DNS analysis.",
     "score": 1,
     "subnet": "86.75.224.0/21"
   }
 ],
 "cats": {
   "Dynamic IPs": 71
 },
 "geo": {
   "country": "France",
   "countrycode": "FR"
 },
 "score": 1,
 "reason": "Third party feed",
 "reasonDescription": "This data was imported from a third party feed.",
 "categoryDescriptions": {
   "Dynamic IPs": "This category contains IP addresses of dialup hosts and DSL lines."
 },
 "tags": []
}
```

"Bots":"IPs known for botnet-member activity. Devices using these IPs are obviously infected and take part in DDoS-attacks

```
"score":7.1}
"geo":{"country":"France"
"score":1}]
"geo":{"country":"France"
"score":1
"score":1
"geo":{"country":"France"
"score":1
```

Comment: As a general rule, awk/grep/sed are best used for unstructured data. When you have structured data (e.g. JSON in your case), you are better off using a tool that knows about the structure (e.g. `jq` as in one of the answers below). The `awk` approach (as in another answer) tends to be fragile: if the format is not exactly as you've presented it, things break - e.g. the `ip` field and its value are assumed to be on the same line: if they are not, the script won't work.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ jq -r '.history | max_by(.score) | .ip' file.json
86.75.227.72/32
```

This uses `jq` to find the entry in the `.history` array that has the maximum `.score` value.  Once that is found, the `.ip` value is extracted from the found entry.

Slight variations in output formats, here with CSV output of IP address, country, company name (if available), and score from the `.history` array:

```
$ jq -r '.history[] | [.ip, .geo.country, .asns."15557".Company, .score] | @csv' file.json
"86.64.0.0/12","France",,1
"86.64.0.0/12","France",,1
"86.72.0.0/14","France",,1
"86.75.224.0/21","France",,1
"86.75.224.0/21","France","LDCOMNET, FR",1
"86.75.224.0/21","France",,1
"86.75.224.0/21","France","LDCOMNET, FR",1
"86.75.227.72/32","France","LDCOMNET, FR",7.1
"86.75.227.72/32","France","LDCOMNET, FR",1
```

And the same, but only taking the maximum score entry:

```
$ jq -r '.history | max_by(.score) | [.ip, .geo.country, .asns."15557".Company, .score] | @csv' file.json
"86.75.227.72/32","France","LDCOMNET, FR",7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` approach:

```
$ awk '$1=="\"ip\":"{
        ip=$2
       }
       $1=="\"country\":"{
        c[ip]=$2
       }
       $1=="\"score\":" && s[ip]<$2{ 
         s[ip]=$2
       }
       END{
           for(ip in c){
            print ip,c[ip],s[ip]
           }
       }' file 
"86.72.0.0/14", "France", 1
"86.64.0.0/12", "France", 1,
"86.75.224.0/21", "France", 1
"86.75.227.72/32", "France", 7.1
"86.75.227.72", "France", 
"86.75.224.0", "France", 1,
```

Or, if you just want the IP with the highest score and nothing else:

```
$ awk '$1=="\"ip\":"{ip=$2}$1=="\"score\":" && score<$2{score=$2;sip=ip}END{print sip} ' file 
"86.75.227.72/32"
```